# What is the best perfomatic way to put a simple icon in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm working in a website with a mobile menu, so had to use a hamburger icon to it.

I found 3 ways:

> 1. Use FontAwesome or some lib like that
> 2. Use a SVG
> 3. Use  the three bars charactere

I exclude  from my options because Font awesome library is a very big lib to use just a simple icon. So I figure out this charactere: `≡`. So I thought: "Omg, i just have to put it on my HTML and it's ok!"

But I was thinking that it is maybe too easy to be true. So i had to come here and ask you guys: Is this correct? Is this supported by browsers in a large scale? Is there a better way to just use a simple icon?

Thanks!

Comment: If you need only one icon - https://css-tricks.com/three-line-menu-navicon/ pseudo elements then

Comment: The char has the fastest loading time obviously! but you have very little control over how it will look on different devices. SVG is the second fastest to load, and about the font, if you want to use lots of icons in your page, it could be a good thing, but if you want it only for one or two icon, it definitely not worth it because user have to load the complete font file (usually >100kb) for icons to get displayed. (personally I would use SVG)

Comment: Nice explanation @Hadi290!! Very clear :)

Answer (score -1):

There is truly no right answer for this but here is a simple solution if you only need the three lines.

```css
.burger{
border-radius:0;
border:0;
width:15px;
height:2px;
background:rgb(0, 0, 0);
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
padding:0;
}
.burger:after,
.burger:before{
content:'';
width:inherit;
height:inherit;
background:inherit;
position:absolute;
top:4px;
left:0;
}
.burger:before{

top:-4px;
}
```

```html
<button class='burger'></button>
```